# Sockets, Cors con Hostinger - Angular y PHP

Tags: php, socket, hosting, cors

Hola estoy haciendo un sistema en Angular con PHP pero tengo estos problemas:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://"rutahosting"/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OhIDRRm' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

De igual manera tengo este error:

> GET https://"rutahosting"/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OhIDRRm net::ERR_FAILED 404

En Angular tengo instalado el ngx-socket-io y en el proxy.conf.json tengo estás configuraciones:

```
{
  "/socket.io": {
    "target": "https://"rutahosting"/Inventario/conteo.php",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true
  },
  "/api": {
    "target": "https://"rutahosting"/Inventario/conteo.php",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

Y en Hostinger tengo mi archivo .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://"rutahosting"/$1 [R=301,L]

<IfModule mod_headers.c> 
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, Accept, Accept-  Version,  Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version, x-api-key, X-Response-Time, X-PINGOTHER, X-CSRF-Token,Authorization"
Header always set Access-Control-Expose-Headers "*"
</IfModule>
```

De igual manera tengo en mi archivo PHP

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); // Allow requests from any origin (Replace * with a specific domain to restrict it)
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE"); // Allow specific HTTP methods
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"); // Allow specific headers
```

No sé que archivo necesito generar ni que configuración tengo que tener para hacer el CORS

Intenté modificar el archivo proxy.conf.json y poner Headers en mi archivo .htaccess, sin embargo no consigo que funcione correctamente, busqué otras alternativas, pero aún no tengo una respuesta satisfactoria.

Comment: proxy.conf.json agregar "logLevel": "debug" pa ver que sucede

Comment: se me ocurre probar el componente con algo como: https://pastebin.com/2zzs2yEd